# Rails unorthodox naming of models with abbreviations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, naming-conventions

In an application I am building I am storing an XML file in my database using the `acts_as_tree` association.  I would like to name the class `XMLElement` but this throws rails off since the capitalization is non-standard.  It is looking for `XMLElement` from the file name `xml_element.rb`.  I tried changing the filename to `x_m_l_element.rb` to try and trick it into thinking that "XML" was really two words, but this didn't work either.  Should I just suck it up and use the name `XmlElement` instead of the more ideal `XMLElement`, or is there a better way around this issue?

Comment: You said:
> but this didn't work either

What was the issue when you tried this?

[We have an `ABExperiment` class, where `AB` is not an acronym, so we don't want to use the `inflect.acronym` solution mentioned below.]

Comment: It doesn't need to be a real acronym. It is merely a tool to inform rails how it should expect default filenames, paths, table names, and namespaces, and class names to be structured.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convention over configuration man.  Suck it up.

Comment: I figured that was the easiest solution, but I didn't know if there was a way to configure it, For example, Rails lets you configure the name of your database table if you have a name you like better, so I thought there might be a way to configure this as well.  I take it there isn't?

Comment: Check the answer below, you can use ActiveSupport inflectors for this

Comment: convention over configuration != only convention is available.

This only means a convention is given. Not even preferred, you can work your whole application without following any convention, it will just be more verbose as you would need to configure or override every unconventional aspect.

No one need to suck it. No part of the application *need* to follow the convention. The convention is there to suggest an expected way to move forward.

You are free to learn and follow or defy and challenge the convention. That's how better conventions are found.

Answer (score 40):

Add the following to `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'XML'
end
```

Now running `$ rails g model XMLElement…` will create a class named `XMLElement` in a file named `xml_element.rb` and an associated table `xml_elements`.

Comment: Still correct, 8 years later. :)

Comment: If only that were true for everything in my life…

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should use XmlElement.

Not only for this example but about every aspect of an application it will never pay off to veer off conventions. There is so much 'magic' going under Rails' hood that it's just not worth it.