# Routing Error Uninitialized Constant Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I click this link on a page `<%= link_to 'Submit an Application', new_s_n_d_sub_path %>` it is giving me the following error:

**Routing Error uninitialized constant SNDSubsController**

This is a simple thing, but I'm not sure where I'm messing up.

I have the `s_n_d_subs_controller.rb` file with:

```
class SNDSubsController < ApplicationController

def new
   ...
end
```

Within views I have the file: `s_n_d_subs/new.html.erb`

Within routes I have `resources :s_n_d_subs`

Rake Routes:

```
    s_n_d_subs GET    /s_n_d_subs(.:format)          s_n_d_subs#index
               POST   /s_n_d_subs(.:format)          s_n_d_subs#create
 new_s_n_d_sub GET    /s_n_d_subs/new(.:format)      s_n_d_subs#new
edit_s_n_d_sub GET    /s_n_d_subs/:id/edit(.:format) s_n_d_subs#edit
     s_n_d_sub GET    /s_n_d_subs/:id(.:format)      s_n_d_subs#show
               PATCH  /s_n_d_subs/:id(.:format)      s_n_d_subs#update
               PUT    /s_n_d_subs/:id(.:format)      s_n_d_subs#update
               DELETE /s_n_d_subs/:id(.:format)      s_n_d_subs#destroy
          root GET    /                              welcome#index
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's this s_n_d_subs? Can't we have a better controller name ?

Comment: You're probably missing a controller class named `SNDSubsController` in your app/controller/ folder

Comment: updated with controller name.  I abbreviated it.  Otherwise it would be very long.

Comment: updated with rake routes.

Comment: Are you sure you correctly copied/pasted your sample controller code from your file into here?  Sounds like it could be a spelling error considering that your error message and class name spelled here are both `SNDSubsController`.

Comment: Given that you're trying to use acronyms, you should either take a look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652347/rails-unorthodox-naming-of-models-with-abbreviations) and consider changing the name to `SndSubsController` instead, or else add an inflector (e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21858530/107277) to allow the filename to be `snd_subs_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just changing the names of my models and regenerating the controllers and views.  I think what was throwing me off was I named my models with single letters representing words: `s_n_d_subs` which was causing  me confusion when I generated controllers and views.  So what I did was changed my model names so each part separated by an underline had at least two letters: ex: `surv_dev.rb`.  This way when I generated controllers and routes it all worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your SNDSubs Is treated as a constant rather than a class. :(
Try this :

```
#app/controllers/sn_d_subs_controller.rb

    class SnDSubsController
      def new
      end
    end

In your routes: 
resources :sn_d_subs
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work.  This is really odd.  I'm sure it is just a small mistake somewhere.